# What does WebAuthenticationDetailsSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to figure out someone else's spring security code. I want to find out what this line of code does, and in general, this particular class. It is described very briefly and incomprehensibly in the documentation.

```
authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetailsSource.java) the class itself is *very* simple.

It has a single responsibility to convert an instance of `HttpServletRequest` class into an instance of the `WebAuthenticationDetails` class. You can think of it as a simple converter.

`HttpServletRequest` object which represents the parsed **raw** HTTP data and is a standard Java class is the input. And the `WebAuthenticationDetails` is an internal Spring class.

Therefore, you can think of it as a bridge between servlet classes and Spring classes.

The `HttpServletRequest` is an ancient class. Goes all the way back to Java 6. ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)). And the other one comes from Spring. ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.html))